# I have to show the value of the UISlider with it I didnt find any method in UISlider to do so

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have to show ths slider values with the movement of the slider. Is there any existing function I can use. Coz I was trying to get a method other than placing labels to show the updated value along with the slider.

Is there a way to show uislider value with slider? or if any other way please reply.

Answer (score 7):

There's no built-in way.

The simplest way to do it is to do have a text label and stuff the slider value into it as the user moves the thumb.

Here's how: create a UISlider and a UILabel in Interface Builder and declare an IBAction in your UIViewController code. Connect the slider's 'Value Changed' outlet to it. Assign the UILabel to an IBOutlet property as well and connect it in IB. Mark the slider as 'continuous' in IB so it keeps sending events as you change it.

In the IBAction method take the sender's `.value` property, format it as a string, and assign it to the label's `.text` property. You can position and format the UILabel anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `UILabel` near the slider and update its value when the slider position is changed.

Answer (score -5):

You can use the following property
[yourslider setShowValue:TRUE];

It will display the value of the slider on right side of the slider. However you might see a warning when building the code but it works, need to see if it is deprecated or not.

Comment: (comment incorrectly posted as a mod-flag): There's no setShowValue method on UISlider - dhttp://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html. If there was, it would take YES and NO instead of TRUE and FALSE as arguments.